# Can't select a specfic row of div when clicking it

Tags: jquery

I can't select a specific row of class of data because of there are multiple class have the same name

```
var set = $("#btn");
set.on("click", function (e) {
    $(e.target).closest("div").toggleClass("#desc");
   alert("ll");
});

var divv = $("div")
divv.on("click", function () {
    alert("help");
    ("#desc").css("display", "normal");
});

 $.get("/api/Items/", function (data) {
        $("#Items").html("");
        $("#Items").append('<span class="success">Loading. . .</span>');
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        $("#Items").html("");
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            var html = '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">' + item.itemTitle + ' <div class="btn btn-default">Read More. . .</div>';
            html += '<div class="desc" style="display:none">' + item.itemDescription + '</div>';
            html += '</div></div>';
            $("#Items").append(html);
        });
    })
     .fail(function () {
         alert("error occurred");
     });
```

When the selected data div is selected, the the desc div will set it's `style="display:normal"` and show.

Comment: There's something fishy with `$(e.target).closest("div").toggleClass("#desc");`. Will you include the output html?

Comment: `display:normal`??? Did you mean `display:block`? Could you please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?